# Application module differs from Data Control Panel

Tags: oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I am using JDeveloper 12c (version 12.1.3) and am encountering strange behaviour in 2 separate applications.  In both cases the list of items in the application module is not reflected in the Data Controls palette in Jdeveloper.

In 1 project, while the application module VO displays correctly, some items in the corresponding Data Control displays twice.  It is also displayed this way in the page's bindings.  For example if the hierarchy is Department -> Employee in the app module, Employee shows up twice under Department in the Data Control panel.

In the 2nd project, the Data Control panel displays more items than is configured in the application module.  For instance, in the Data Control panel, the listing shows Employee and Activities under Department while the Application Module only has Department -> Employee set up.  Activities is a legitimate child of Department but for some reason has disappeared from the Application Module.

Both these examples were simplified - there are nested and master-detail hierarchies in these applications.  Nevertheless, is there any way to synchronise the Application Module and the Data Controls panel?  Did a file get corrupted?  How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: The 'Data Control' has a refresh button. You could also try to restart JDeveloper but I guess you have tried those option already?

Comment: Yes, I tried those suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

One note is that the data control panel will only show what is in the AM data model - which might not be all the VOs and links you have in your project.

It might be worth going into the am.xml file to check if there are duplicates in there.
Then verify that the datacontrols.dcx file points to the right AM file.